# How can I assign the return value of the $.post to a variable

Tags: jquery, .post

my code is

```
data1 = "";

$('#send').click(function(){
   var post = $(this).val();

   $.post('post.php',{post:post},function(data){
      data1 = data;
   });

   $(this).val(data1);
});
```

it seems that all process of the function .click is executed before executing the $.post function. Can anybody help me.

Comment: That's because .post() is asynchronous.

Comment: I have no idea why this question got up voted. It is asked daily, and is one of the most basic things about Ajax. It's even in the first letter of Ajax!

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Not everybody is an AJAX expert, nor do people know the right terminology to Google. If you can find a question that the OP can look through to understand exactly how to solve his problem, tag this question as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @Blender I'm on mobile. I bet the full site sidebar has dupes

Answer (score 7):

`.post()` is asynchronous, which means that it runs in the background and doesn't block the execution of the functions after it. Before `data1 = data` is set, `$(this).val()` is already called.

Try coding everything that depends upon `data` in the `$.post()` function's callback:

```
$('#send').click(function() {
  $.post('post.php', {
    post: $(this).val()
  }, function(data) {
    $('#send').val(data);
  });
});
```